# json data loading in browser tools, but not on web page

Tags: javascript, json

Hi all and thanks in advance for your suggestions.

We have an online questionnaire that has been running live for several months with no problems.  Now however when we clone the questionnaire to use it for a similar site, with different data sources (json), the json are visible in dev tools/console on page load BUT only one of them loads in the html but not the second.  We've recloned and rebuilt and still cannot figure out why the json is not showing up on the page in this second site, when everything is perfect on the first.

Concrete example of working code:
http://---
in the dev tools --> Network, you'll see that two json load (questions.json and categories.json) and these display on the page

Concrete example of NON working code:
http://----
everything is **exactly** the same as the above except that we are now loading two different json files, from the same server as the working code, but from a different sub-directory chain.
in the dev tools --> Network/console, you'll see that two different json load (still named questions.json and categories.json but from different paths) but now the questions don't load in the page.

We are stuck and grateful for any suggestions.
Thanks, 
Benj

Comment: Thank you fresh eyes!  That was it: category is not text string but variable.  Reset and now we are good to go - **THANKS!**

Comment: Could you please describe the error?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to debug your application and mentioned 1 differences:

http://178.62.238.105/factory/data-specific/pcos/en/pcos-full/categories.json

returns

```js
....
{
  "catId" : 0,
  "category" : "Abdomen*",
  "description" : "What'......"
}
....
```

Other link

http://178.62.238.105/factory/js/fertility-full/en/data/categories.json

returns:

```js
...
{
  "catId" : 0,
  "category" : "Abdomen",
  "description" : "What's hap......"
}
...
```

So categories have different names (`Abdomen` and `Abdomen*`. I think it causes an error

Comment: Yep in FutureBabyQuiz this loop isn't matching anything: 
   `if(item.qcat===p_currentCategory){
    g_questionListPerCat.push(item);
   }`